# Форматирование текста сообщения для телеграм-бота

Tags: telegram-bot, google-apps-script

Создан телеграм-бот, который по запросу отправляет определенные данные из гугл-таблицы.
Сообщение собирается и форматируется так:

```
          text += 'Конверсия: ' + sheet.getRange("B3").getDisplayValue() + ' | ' + '<i>' + sheet.getRange("C3").getDisplayValue() + '</i>\n';
          text += 'Лиды:' + '          ' + sheet.getRange("B4").getDisplayValue() + ' | ' + sheet.getRange("C4").getDisplayValue() + '\n';
          text += 'Сделки:' + '      ' + sheet.getRange("B5").getDisplayValue() + ' | ' + sheet.getRange("C5").getDisplayValue() + '\n';
          text += 'Выручка:' + '    ' + sheet.getRange("B6").getDisplayValue() + ' | ' + sheet.getRange("C6").getDisplayValue() + '\n';
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить код, чтобы в тексте сообщения числа всегда были по правому краю вне зависимости от количества символов? Примерно как на картинке[image: бот модулькассы]

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм достаточно простой.

- Допустим каждая строка состоит из трех частей, слева направо: `txt`, `spaces`, `num`.
- Допустим шрифт моноширинный и известно максимальное число букв в строке `max`.

Нужно посчитать количество пробелов перед тем как формировать строку.

- Переводим цифры в текст и узнаем количество символов: `len = num.toString().length`
- Складываем полученное число с длинной текста: `len = txt.length + len`
- Вычитаем эту сумму из длинны строки: `len = max - len`
- Формируем пробельный элемент: `spaces = ' '.repeat(len)`

Одним словом:

```
var spaces = max - (num.toString().length + txt.length)
```

Дальше формируем строку: `text` + `spaces` + `num`

Это можно реализовать в виде вспомогательной функции и использовать в цикле формирующем таблицу. Примерно так:

```js
const max  = 25;
const txts = ['наличными', 'по карте', 'aванс'];
const nums = ['100', '0', '25'];
var  table = '';

function get_line(txt, num, max) {
    var spaces = max - (num.toString().length + txt.length);
    return txt + ' '.repeat(spaces) + num + '\n';
}

for (let i=0; i<txts.length; i++) table += get_line(txts[i], nums[i], max);

console.log(table);
```

Результат:

```
наличными             100
по карте                0
aванс                  25
```

Comment: Юрий, благодарю за ответ! Код работает, количество символов в строках с учетом пробелов равное, но визуально в сообщении ТГ столбцы съезжают. Видимо, это связано с различным размером символов в шрифте ТГ. Можете помочь разобраться?

Comment: Если шрифт не моноширинный (все буквы, цифры и пр. одной ширины, как в печатной машинке) то такой фокус с добавлением пробелов не пройдёт. И у вас на скриншоте шрифт моноширинный. Надо разобраться, как вам такой же шрифт включить в телеграме. Возможно бот умеет при формировании сообщения указывать каким шрифтом это сообщение должно отображаться. Это я не знаю.

Comment: с помощью [форматирования](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options) Markdown или HTML